# How to reformat text inside a .txt file

Tags: notepad++, text-formatting

I have some database information in a notepad file, it looks like this;

```
    firstname:lastname
    =====
    [Age]: Answer
    [Sex]: Answer
    [Height]: Answer
    [Shoe]: Answer
    =====

    firstname:lastname
    =====
    [Age]: Answer
    [Sex]: Answer
    [Height]: Answer
    [Shoe]: Answer
    =====

    firstname:lastname
    =====
    [Age]: Answer
    [Sex]: Answer
    [Height]: Answer
    [Shoe]: Answer
    =====
```

I would like to to appear on one line, for example;

```
firstname:lastname=====[Age]: Answer[Sex]: Answer[Height]: Answer[Shoe]: Answer=====
firstname:lastname=====[Age]: Answer[Sex]: Answer[Height]: Answer[Shoe]: Answer=====
firstname:lastname=====[Age]: Answer[Sex]: Answer[Height]: Answer[Shoe]: Answer=====
```

What would be the best way to achieve this, if possible?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: where does the database information come from, what do you feed it into afterwards? That will limit your choices. CSV would seem like a good way as of now.

Comment: @flolilolilo - It was a questionnaire to work out some information prior to restocking a webstore which sells footwear. The information right now is in a .txt document, I am wanting EACH individual piece of data on one line, rather than on 7 so we can use the marking tools within Notepad++ to separate it. I am not looking for any help on how its going to be used after, I am specifically looking for advice on how to break down the data into single lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\R(?!\R)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\R      : any kind of linebreak
(?!\R)  : negative lookahead, make sure we don't have another linebreak after
```

**Result for given example:**

```
firstname:lastname=====[Age]: Answer[Sex]: Answer[Height]: Answer[Shoe]: Answer=====
firstname:lastname=====[Age]: Answer[Sex]: Answer[Height]: Answer[Shoe]: Answer=====
firstname:lastname=====[Age]: Answer[Sex]: Answer[Height]: Answer[Shoe]: Answer=====
```

Comment: This is why I love this site, thank you so much toto honestly I really do appreciate it. Your explanation has also helped in understanding how its done and how I can apply this in future scenarios.

Comment: @MrBlobby: You're welcome, glad it helps.